# ng2-file-upload is setting the wrong Content-Type

Tags: angular, file-upload

I followed this tutorial:
https://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/

It works just fine with Postman but when I try it in my app it doesn't. From the api I return files and I see them from Postman but get undefined in my app.

I did notice that in my app my request Content-Type is set to:

```
text/plain;charset=UTF-8
```

I tried to set to:

```
multipart/form-data
```

But then got a Boundry error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I changed this on the server:

```
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('files'))
```

to:

```
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
```

and it started to work, no idea why postman was working.